# Can you assign an IP to a hostname that's assigned to another IP?

Tags: ip, hostname

Yes, it sounds a bit inceptiony, but here's the reasoning.

I need a static IP and one cannot be purchased. My router does support DynDNS however. Which means my dynamic IP is associated with a static hostname such as example.dyn.org.

Most firewalls require an IP or IP range and don't support hostnames. Meaning I can't add "example.dyn.org" to the firewall. My question is, can I buy another IP and assign that to example.dyn.org, and add that IP to firewalls? And thus that IP would reflect the underlying IP.

While not positive, I assume that's not possible but thought I'd ask as I imagine countless users who have dynamic IP's are looking for such as solution.

Comment: There's something unclear to me in your question: you said a static IP address cannot be purchased, so what kind of IP are you willing to use?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Is the firewall in question one you have access to?

Comment: I mean through my internet provider I can't purchase a static IP for my internet. I can of course however buy a static IP from a webhost without a problem.

Comment: No, I don't have access to the hypothetical firewalls. That is say I have 20 people. Each only allow me to access their servers from an IP that's allowed in their firewalls. Currently I have to tell them all to update my IP everytime it changes. Some support hostnames such as example.dyn.org, but for most they require an IP number, which leads me to my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you've set up a DNS A record for example.dyn.org to point at a static IP address that your router doesn't actually have, that doesn't mean that your traffic will magically start to originate from that IP address instead of your dynamic IP address -- it will have no effect whatsoever on your IP address as seen by other people's firewalls, it will just stop people from connecting to you using the hostname.

Comment: The router automatically updates the hostname "example.dyn.org" to reflect whatever my IP address is at the moment. The "magic" is in the service provided by DynDNS. So when you add that hostname to a firewall it will always reflect my current IP address. That part isn't the problem however. The issue is that most firewalls don't support adding hostnames to allowed addresses and rather only accept IP (numbers).

Comment: Sure, but the router changes the hostname to match the IP address. It can't change the IP address to match the hostname, which seems to be what you want it to do.

Comment: No not looking to change an IP. Rather asking if an IP can be assigned to a hostname (and that hostname is already assigned to another IP). So that the first IP flows through to the second. I'm assuming the answer is no, but that's what I'm trying to find out definitively. ServerFault said to try here.

Comment: IP addresses can't "flow through" to each other.